# Появляется ошибка 403 при запросе к API ruGPT-3

Tags: javascript, python, requests, fetch

Появляется ошибка при запросе к https://api.aicloud.sbercloud.ru/public/v1/public_inference/gpt3/predict. Хотя на самом сайте всё работает https://russiannlp.github.io/rugpt-demo/.
Код на Python:

```
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
     API_URL = 'https://api.aicloud.sbercloud.ru/public/v1/public_inference/gpt3/predict'
    session = requests.Session()
    payload = {"text": "Текст"}
    params = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf8')
    req = session.post(API_URL, data=params, headers=headers)
```

Код на JavaScript с самого сайта:

```
const response = fetch('https://api.aicloud.sbercloud.ru/public/v1/public_inference/gpt3/predict', {
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: "same-origin",
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({text: 'Текст'}),
    })
```

При этом при попытке выполнения этого кода на своём сайте появляется ошибка 403.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте дополнительные значения headers в запрос.

На питоне это выглядит так:

```
import requests
word = "Макс: Привет\nВика: Как у тебя дела?\nНина:"

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Server': 'istio-envoy',
    'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.43',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://russiannlp.github.io',
    'Referer': 'https://russiannlp.github.io/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es-AR;q=0.8,es;q=0.7',
    }

response = requests.post("https://api.aicloud.sbercloud.ru/public/v1/public_inference/gpt3/predict",
                         json={"text": word}, headers=headers)

print('Status code:', response.status_code)
answer = response.json()
print(answer['predictions'])
```

Ответ:

```
Status code: 200
Макс: Привет
Вика: Как у тебя дела?
Нина: У меня всё классно!
Макс и Вика смеются.
Н.В.: Как вы познакомились, как познакомились вообще? (хором)
В.М.: Случайно! Я шла, и мне навстречу шёл парень. Он был такой красивый, высокий, тёмные волосы, зелёные глаза!
Н: И что?
В.: И я влюбилась!
В: (подсказывает Макс)
Н.: Да! Влюбилась в него с первого взгляда!
```